# Python script header

Tags: python, scripting

The typical header should be

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

But I found below also works when executing the script like `$python ./my_script.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#!python
```

What's difference between these 2 headers? What could be the problem for 2nd one? Please also discussing the case for python interpreter is in PATH or not. Thanks.

Comment: that header is called Shebang http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29

Comment: FYI when you run a script in the manner `$ python ./my_script.py` (specifying `python` explicitly), the shebang (`#!`) line is ignored. It only has an effect if you run the script as an executable, e.g. `$ ./my_script.py`.

Comment: @David Zaslavsky: +1 Good catch.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

First, any time you run a script using the interpreter explicitly, as in

```
$ python ./my_script.py
$ ksh ~/bin/redouble.sh
$ lua5.1 /usr/local/bin/osbf3
```

the `#!` line is always ignored.  The `#!` line is a Unix feature of *executable* scripts only, and you can see it documented in full on the [man page for `execve(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve).  There you will find that the word following `#!` must be the pathname of a valid executable.  So

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

executes whatever `python` is on the users `$PATH`.  This form is resilient to the Python interpreter being moved around, which makes it somewhat more portable, but it also means that the user can override the standard Python interpreter by putting something ahead of it in `$PATH`.  Depending on your goals, this behavior may or may not be OK.

Next,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

deals with the common case that a Python interpreter is installed in `/usr/bin`.  If it's installed somewhere else, you lose.  But this is a good way to ensure you get exactly the version you want or else nothing at all ("fail-stop" behavior), as in

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.5
```

Finally,

```
#!python
```

works only if there is a `python` executable in the current directory when the script is run.  Not recommended.

Answer (score 39):

I'd suggest 3 things in the beginning of your script:

First, as already being said use environment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Second, set your encoding:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Third, set some doc string:

```
"""This is a awesome
    python script!"""
```

And for sure I would use `"    "` (4 spaces) for ident.
Final header will look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""This is a awesome
        python script!"""
```

Best wishes and happy coding.

Comment: Just to support the seemingly opinionated comment on spaces over tabs: "Spaces are the preferred indentation method." (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces)

Answer (score 5):

The Python executable might be installed at a location other than /usr/bin, but `env` is nearly always present in that location so using `/usr/bin/env`is more portable.

Answer (score 2):

From the manpage for `env` (GNU coreutils 6.10):

```
env - run a program in a modified environment
```

In theory you could use `env` to reset the environment (removing many of the existing environment variables) or add additional environment variables in the script header. Practically speaking, the two versions you mentioned are identical. (Though others have mentioned a good point: specifying `python` through `env` lets you abstractly specify `python` without knowing its path.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is - python may not be in `/usr/bin`, but for example in `/usr/local/bin` (BSD).

When using virtualenv, it may even be something like `~/projects/env/bin/python`

Answer (score 0):

The `/usr/bin/env python` becomes very useful when your scripts depend on environment settings for example using scripts which rely on `python virtualenv`. Each virtualenv has its own version of python binary which is required for adding packages installed in virtualenv to python path (without touching PYTHONPATH env).

As more and more people have started to used virtualenv for python development **prefer to use `/usr/bin/env python` unless you don't want people to use their custom python binary.**

Note: You should also understand that there are potential security issues (in multiuser environments) when you let people run your scripts in their custom environments. You can get some ideas from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Security_issues).